# How to change "Continue to Force.com" to "Contineu to <company name>" in Google SSO with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, authprovider

We implemented Single sign on with Google as authentication provider for Salesforce.
It is working well. However, in the Google's login page, it shows force.com and we want to see our company name.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNhUh.png)